# Symfony does not read or update certain fields of a mysql entity (only in the production env - a ubuntu vps)

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine

Ok so I generated an entity and its form with Symfony.

Then I added a field by hand:

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="icon_name", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $icon;
```

I then did `doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql` and pasted the resulting query into my production database on a ubuntu vps with Sequel Pro. Then I edited some of the values by hand.

I then did `doctrine:update:entities`and added the missing field to the generated FormType.

Now I can use the Form and it reads and writes to the database just fine on my development machine, but as soon as I try it on the production machine it does not work.

I cleared all caches on the production machine, too. And the form field is visible but does not function. All other fields work as they did before.

`doctrine:schema:validate` gives me two "OK"s on the production machine.

Anything else I can try?

Comment: What exactly 'does not work'?

Comment: reading or writing values from/into the database for this field

Comment: you may have cache on entities, try to restart apache / nginx or php-fpm OR clear your apc cache with `php -r "apc_clear_cache(); apc_clear_cache('user'); apc_clear_cache('opcode');"`